# App crashed when load retrieved value to listView

Tags: android, image, sqlite, listview, android-listview

In `AddClaims`, I save `ListView` (with data and image) into SQLite database.

**AddClaims**

```
 ArrayList<ImageAndText> images=new ArrayList<ImageAndText>();

  btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { //  button is clicked
                SB.insertStaffBenefit(images, a); // SB is the object of StaffAPI
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

**StaffAPI**

```
 public long insertStaffBenefit(ArrayList<ImageAndText> imageText,long id)
    {
        id1=id;
        database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        for(ImageAndText i:imageText) {
        String description=i.getDescription();
        Bitmap image=i.getImage();
        byte[]data=getBitmapAsByteArray(image);
        values.put(MydatabaseHelper.Description,description);
        values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Image, data);
        database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_STAFF_BENEFIT, null, values);
        }
        database.close();
        return 0 ;
    }

public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap)
    {    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
        Log.e("TAG", "Blob size: " + outputStream.size() / 1024 + " KB");
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

I not sure whether this is the correct way to save the image in `listView`, but it can display the `Blob` size. So I assume the image can be saved.

Next, I wanted to retrieve all the image and loaded to `ListView` in **EditStaff**

**EditStaff**

```
  public void BuildEditStaffList(long id)
    {
        Log.e("S", id+"");
        sqlcon.open();
        Cursor cursor1=sqlcon.readName(id);

        String[] columns=new String[]{
                MydatabaseHelper.image,MyDatabaseHelper.Description};

        int[] to=new int[]
                {
                        R.id.image,R.id.description};

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.retrieve_staff,
                cursor1,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        listViewEdit.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

**StaffAPI**

```
 public Cursor readName(long id)
    {
        Log.e("ID",id+"");
        Cursor c=database.rawQuery(" SELECT _id, Image, Description FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_STAFF_BENEFIT  + "  WHERE Ts_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        Log.e("ID",id+"");
        return c;
    }
```

The app crashed when I try to retrieve the image and text to ListView EditStaff. I check the logCat, **but it only throw me**

```
W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e46c80)
```

After I remove the  `MydatabaseHelper.image` and  `R.id.image` in **EditStaff**, **the text can be displayed on `listView`.** So I guess the app crashed is because of the image. Is there any way to check whether the image is inserted correctly in `SQLite`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the picture in your local storage and store the path to access it in the database.

Please notice java methods should respect camel case syntax, starting with a lower case.

Also, use a worker thread to interact with a SQLite database

Comment: So this is the only way to save multiple image?  Cannot use bitmap?

Comment: Your way should work but it is not recommended. I think your raw request has a problem in the where clause. A . is missing between Ts and _id.

Comment: Please mark the question as resolved if this did help you

Comment: It doesn't help much. However, thanks for your suggestions